# Getting records from past 24 months from start of month

Tags: sql-server

My team is wanting a pivot table showing sales per month for the past 24 months for each item we carry.  I am a little stuck getting the past 24 months from our sales table.  My issue is I can get close, but for January 2016 it is only showing mid month.

`where invoicedate >= DATEADD(MONTH, -24, GETDATE())`

I have been using the following query but am a little stuck in what I need to change to get from 2016-01-01 without hard-coding that as a date.

Comment: I think my question was somewhat different but was able to figure out how to use what you linked.  What I needed ended up being:  DATEADD(MONTH, -24, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0))

Comment: That was the intent! Glad you got it sorted.